# Video invertido HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5

Gostaria de saber como que faço para que quando der play no vídeo, ele comece de traz para frente em um loop infinito.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5277293/4056678

Comment: @re22 Transforma em resposta :)

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente isso é impossível. Uma vez que a tag HTML5  reproduz um vídeo por *streaming*, no sentido do **início para o fim**, isto é, vai reproduzindo à medida que vai recebendo, e o navegador fica impossibilitado de reproduzir os últimos frames do vídeo (do fim para o início), porque eles ainda não foram carregados.

Entretanto, existe um código [NESTA PÁGINA](https://codepen.io/adrianparr/pen/qmCek) que faz o vídeo correr de trás pra frente. Porém não creio que ele irá atender ao que propõe a sua pergunta.